# Is there an event callback to know when html5 <audio> has loaded the audio and is playable?

Tags: html, audio

I have  controls that load mp3 files from other sites, but if it take the audio file a while to start loading, the controls stay disabled for a few seconds and appear not to be working.

If I show an activity indicator when the audio control starts loading the resource, is there a callback I can use to hide the indicator when the audio control is ready to start playing the audio and ready for user interaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`element.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', callback, false);`

apart form `loadedmetadata`, `load` can also be used to see if the song is also loaded

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension

Comment: `load` is not fired on Firefox and Chrome. `loadedmetadata` is ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use events on MediaControllers:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#handler-mediacontroller-oncanplay

Example:

```
var controller = new MediaController();
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.controller = controller;
audio.oncanplay = function (event) {};
```